# how to install io-console-0.4.3 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using the following gem:

```
gem install io-console -v 0.4.3
```

Im receiving the following error(s):

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'io-console' (= 0.4.3) in any
>   repository
>
> ERROR:  Possible alternatives: io-console

iIam doing this, but these error are received by me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the available version of gem. [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/io-console/versions/0.4.2)

io-console available versions are:

```
0.4.6 - December 23, 2015 (21 KB)
0.4.5 - December 24, 2015 (21 KB)
0.4.2 - February 16, 2013 (9 KB)
0.4.1 - February 4, 2013 (8.5 KB)
0.3 - June 24, 2011 (6.5 KB).
```

Thus rails Could not find a valid gem version for `io-console`.

you can install any version of `io-console` from above available version list.